# Ubuntu GNOME boots to grey screen with border

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I have just finished installing Ubuntu GNOME version 16.04 and when I boot (UEFI) I am presented with a grey screen with a darker grey border. I have tried get into the command line with shift and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> and it has not worked. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer for me was to just install normal Ubuntu from Canonical. When it booted, Unity looked really messed up (I think it was Compiz), but I went into the Terminal and installed GNOME desktop from there, restarted, installed graphics drivers, and now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've spent around 5-6 hours trying to make it work. Now, it works! What I did was change the BIOS from Legacy to UEFI, reinstalled Ubuntu GNOME, restarted, waited for a bit, and works. Hope this can work for you too :)

Edit: I restarted and got the grey screen with the border again, but only for around 5 seconds. Afterwards, it'll boot into the login screen.

Comment: If you have any ideas on what caused the issue, that would certainly be appreciated.  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!